# Eclipse not linking private member names for library with attached source

Tags: java, eclipse

Working in Eclipse 3.7.2 on a Java project.

1. I added a jar containing binaries for a third-party library to the build path.
2. I set the `Source attachment` for this library to the jar containing the source.

When I go to one of the classes from this library, the source shows properly.  However, **private members are not named in the outline view, nor in the** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> **dialog, and I cannot navigate to them without using the `Find/Replace` dialog.**  They are referenced by letters of the alphabet (`a`, `b`, `c`, etc.) in the order they were declared in the class, but clicking those letters in the Outline tab does not bring me to their declaration in the source.  This applies to both private fields and private methods.

Is there any configuration I can do to fix this?

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: It almost looks like the code was run through an obfuscator: have  you tried decompiling the code and seeing if it matches the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The private methods in this library have been obfuscated, there is nothing you will be able to do to get around seeing this. If the library is open source you can recompile it yourself without obfuscation but chances are these methods are being intentionally kept from view. This isn't such a terrible thing, considering private methods/varibales/fields can't be accessed from outside the library anyway. You can't access any of these methods or fields yourself so it shouldn't make a difference in the long run.

Comment: The debugger does step into those methods, obfuscated or not. And if you need to put a breakpoint somewhere in one of those methods to understand what is going on, you can't. So, yes, it is a terrible thing, for me at least.